# Access api's written in laravel 5.2 without using index.php file (Ubuntu 14.04 in Azure)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I am trying to access api's written in laravel though postman. 
By using the below format link i am able to access the api's
http://example.cloudapp.net/suven/index.php/api/register

But how to access without index.php name in the url

I have 2 laravel projects created in /home/azureuser

Below is my **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/api.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.cloudapp.net

        Alias /suven /home/azureuser/webservices/public
        <Directory /home/azureuser/webservices/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /quiz /home/azureuser/quizapp/public
        <Directory /home/azureuser/quizapp/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Below is my **.htaccess** file in /webservices/public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /webservices/public

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Below is my **routes.php** file

```
Route::get('/', function ()
{
    return view('errors/503');
});


Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/'), function()
{
    Route::post('/register','UserAuthController@register');
    Route::post('/login','UserAuthController@login');
});

Route::group(array('middleware' => 'appuser_auth','prefix' => 'api/'), function()
{
    Route::post('/changepassword','UserAuthController@changePassword');
});
```

Comment: can someone please reply to this.

Comment: Me too looking for the answer but no success.